# Why does `map` on a Directive sometimes wrap the result in a tuple?

Tags: scala, akka-http

The following [example from the the Akka HTTP docucumentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/custom-directives.html#map-and-tmap) shows that you can use the `map` method on `Directives` to transform their value much like you expect.

```
val textParam: Directive1[String] =
  parameter("text".as[String])

val lengthDirective: Directive1[Int] =
  textParam.map(text => text.length)
```

However, when I try to utilize this with my own examples, I get a directive of `Tuple1` of the expected type rather than a directive of the expected type itself.  For example:

```
val stringOpsDirective: Directive[Tuple1[StringOps]] =
  textParam.map(text => augmentString(text))
```

I see that `map` takes an implicit `Tupler` parameter but looking the implementations could find of the trait,  I don't see how everything is not wrapped in a `Tuple`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your use of map you declared a subtly different, but equivalent, return type declared than was utilized in the examples.  The examples return type 'Directive**1**' where you return type 'Directive'.

If you utilize `Directive1`, your example takes the same form as those in the documentation:

```
val stringOpsDirective: Directive1[StringOps] =
  textParam.map(text => augmentString(text))
```

This works because `Directive1[_]` is an alias for `Directive[Tuple1[_]]` as defined below:

```
type Directive1[T] = Directive[Tuple1[T]]
```

In other words, you were right, every `Directive` is parametrically typed to some kind of `Tuple`.  However, you can use the type `Directive1` to somewhat hide that fact in the case of `Tuple1`.